Customized Bootstrap Carousel doesnt work properly with flex and gap
I i have a customized bootstrap carousel, where instead of showing one div i show 3 ( one in middle and 50% of the ones on the sides ).
My problem is my divs have borders and i try to set up a gap between them using display: flex and gap: 10px which works fine, but when the carousel moves the gap vanish and re-appear again, which results in a unpleasant effect. Video 
Here is my HTML code : 
<div id="newProductsCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item product-item active">
      <div class="product_card">
        <div class="product_card__img">
          <a href="..." class="product_card__link">
          <img src="..." alt="Gel Lavant">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="product_card__description">
          <a href="..." class="product_card__brand">Mitosyl</a>
          <a href="..." class="product_card__link">
            <h3 class="product_card__title">Gel Lavant</h3>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item product-item">...</div>
    <div class="carousel-item product-item">...</div>
    <div class="carousel-item product-item">...</div>
    <div class="carousel-item product-item">...</div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#newProductsCarousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#newProductsCarousel" data-bs-slide="next">
  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </button>
</div>

Sass code 
//Mobile
.newProductsCarousel {
  .carousel {
    overflow: hidden;

    &-item {
      .product_card:first-child,
      .product_card:last-child {
        display: none;
      }

      .product_card {
        height: 340px;
        text-align: center;
      }
    }
  }
}
// Desktop
.newProductsCarousel {
    $fragment_width: 25%;

    .carousel-item-next:not(.carousel-item-start),
    .carousel-item-end.active {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(33%);
      transform: translateX(33%);
    }
    .carousel-item-prev:not(.carousel-item-end),
    .carousel-item-start.active {
     -webkit-transform: translateX(-33%);
      transform: translateX(-33%);
    }

    .carousel {
      &-inner {
        width: (100% - 2 * $fragment_width) * 3;
        left: 3 * $fragment_width - 100%;
      }

      &-item {
        &.active {
          display: flex;
          column-gap: 20px;
        }

        .product_card {
          display: block !important;
          height: 340px;
          width: 33.33333333%;
          float: left;
          text-align: center;
          position: relative;
          padding: 30px 0;
        }
      }
    }
  }

JS Code :
    $('.carousel-item.product-item').each(function () {
        var next = $(this).next();
        if (!next.length) {
            next = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }
        next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    }).each(function () {
        var prev = $(this).prev();
        if (!prev.length) {
            prev = $(this).siblings(':last');
        }
        prev.children(':nth-last-child(2)').clone().prependTo($(this));
    });

I tried giving the display: flex; to all carousel-item, but it didnt work, it broke my carousel from moving.
I also tried giving the maring to the middle div, but it resulted in the same effect.

Your question is really about CSS, so you should be showing us rendered HTML and compiled CSS in a demo snippet so we don't have to compile in our minds. Please see [ask] and take the [tour].

What about using margins, like margin-right?
.carousel-item {
  margin-right: 10px;
}


yes i tried it, no luck
